# Android WebView rendering with HTML

Tags: android, html, css, webview

When I let a  show and hide on webview, it always remain fragment on screen util I touch the screen.
    for example, when click a button, show a div, however, the div is not show completely, it only show half, if I touch the screen, the left part showed.then, when click the button to let this div hide, it doesn't hide totally, it only hide part, remaining part on screen until I touch the screen, the left part dispeared.

```
1. I use jquery show() and hide() method to show and hide the div
2. I have enabled hardware accelerate
3. I have set webview render priority as HIGH.

would you please give me some suggestions, thank you.
```

Actually, this is a post from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/UzWMukIo4xg), I just encountered the same problem.

In my project, I got a div including two buttons. I also have to show/hide the div in certain circumstances. More specifically, fixed positioning is used to pin the div at the bottom of browser like a footer. Here is the css of div.

```
[id^="btns_div"]{
position: fixed;
bottom: 5px;
left: 10px;
z-index: 3;
background-color:#eeeeff;
width: 90%;
height: 10%;
font-size:20px;
display: none;
}
```

I tried many different mechanisms trying to avoid this rendering problem. I just figure out that the problem only occurs when css:bottom is assigned. Without it, no rendering problem but wrong position.

Any Suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience full hardware acceleration on a webview for page that play with the DOM causes millions of problems at the moment. I have done a lot of tests trying to find a possible root cause, but looks like there's little we can do if Google / Chromium don't work themselves.

HArdware acceleration causes the screen to be rendered in a completely different way, using "display lists". As a very cheap resume, this technique has thousands of benefits but is not very good at detecting non-expected updates, so the user has to have this in mind and "invalidate" the rendering.

This is excellent for Java apps, because you are programming right where the action is, but when you insert a webview things start to get complicated. Please google display lists for an extended explanation,  it's really worth it to understand why these things happen.

So in my experience I have to always disable hard acceleration for the webview. Every now and then I try new android versions and all, but the situation does not improve at all.

If anybody has better news please tell!
cheers.